# Can FFmpeg concat and drawtext at the same time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I can successfully use FFmpeg's concat filter and the drawtext filter in separate commands.

But this requires two encoding runs.

Is it possible to get both of these filters to work in a chain, so that only one encoding takes place?  How?

I have three video clips I am trying to concatenate and I want one common text to appear over the resulting video.

Comment: Are the videos with different codecs / encoding settings? If not you could use the concat demuxer or protocol instead of the filter.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the videos have different encoding settings and I cannot control this.  To join them, I must use the concat filter.  But I cannot figure out how to combine the concat filter with the drawtext filter in one statement.

Comment: Please include some information (the complete console output) about your inputs: `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3`

Comment: I'm on Windows. How do I produce the complete console output that you would like to see?

Comment: :) Thanks, but I know how to direct the output of FFmpeg to a text file.  What I meant was I do not know how to run FFmpeg on my three input files so that it produces the report you want.  I tried: ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3.  When doing so I replaced the inputs with my actual three videos.  The only output was an error message that I did not provide an output.  So what is this complete console output?  Thanks.

Comment: Something like this [example](http://pastebin.com/Kc41y8En).

Comment: I had an answer with example images ready and waiting for you to provide the console output (I wanted to make sure it will work for you with no guesswork), so make sure for next time to provide the proper info and you'll get an answer much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile1 -i inputfile2 -y \
-filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a];\
[v]drawtext=fontsize=72:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf:text=Text Line To Render:x=(w)/2:y=(h)/2[o]'\
-map '[o]' -map '[a]' ...other encoding parameters... outputfile
```

Note that `[v]` and `[a]` are just labels – you could very well use `[p]` and `[q]` and that would be fine too. Only stream 0 goes to first label and stream 1 to second label. So I'm assuming stream 0 is video.

You have to ensure that the streams in `inputfile1` and `inputfile2` have the same order. Then we pass the output of video stream as input to the drawtext filter by saying `[v]drawtext=....`

The output of this is now labeled as `[o]` at the end of the `drawtext` parameters. By saying `-map [o]`, we use the output from `drawtext` to pass on forward to your other encoding parameters.

The font path I'm using is from OpenSUSE. Yours could be different.