# Can ffmpeg concat and drawtext at the same time using input from a file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

Sorry guys, I am new to this site and new to ffmpeg. I am a using ffmpeg to concat videos by taking input from a file as shown below.

mistakes.txt

```
file VID_20191031_030050.mp4
inpoint 2222
outpoint 2233
file VID_20191031_030050.mp4
inpoint 2350
outpoint 2364
```

I am using the following command to concat multiple clips whose inpoint and outpoints are read from a single file(**mistakes.txt**). I am writing the output to **VID_20191031_030050_mistakes.mp4**.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mistakes.txt VID_20191031_030050_mistakes.mp4
```

Basically I have sports video and I am trying to see my mistakes in a single clip. I also want to display a text on the screen which includes the details of that specific mistake. For now lets say that I want the name of the file i.e. mistake to be displayed on the bottom right corner of the screen. Is there an efficient way to do this.

I have gone through this link([Can FFmpeg concat and drawtext at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/663439/can-ffmpeg-concat-and-drawtext-at-the-same-time)), but I couldn't map it to my problem, as I am new to ffmpeg.

P.S. I am using python3 to automate the editing of my sports clips.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chicken-and-egg problem: Once you use the `concat` input format, the name of the "real" current file is no longer accessible to the image processing engine - all it knows is "mistakes.txt".

You can

- either draw on the raw clips and then concat them without reencoding (this is nearly as fast as doing it in one go)
- or draw on the concatenated file with a fitting timeline. A good trick for that is to create a **subtitle** file from your inpoints and outpoints and use the `subtitles` filter to render it in.